# SO account for DevDays sign-up - what for?

Tags: discussion, devdays

A colleague has just bought me a London DevDays ticket - woohoo! - but he needed my SO account URL to sign me up.

Obviously I don't object to linking my ticket to my account here but I'm curious what you're going to do with that. Are you planning to

- print my rep / badges / global flair on my pass?
- print my gravatar on my pass?
- print different colour passes for different levels of rep?
- something else?

i.e. do I need to make sure I hit 10K before November, or some sooner cut-off when you print the badges (when?), and get an up-to-date photo for my gravatar, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: They use it to sign you up for a Chutney's of the World account. Enjoy.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Excellent! My brother gave me a cheese and port hamper for Christmas and [the chutney in it](http://www.thecheeseworks.co.uk/cheese_gift_boxes_product.php?id=16) was really good. I look forward to more.

Comment: Spotted today: sidebar ad offering me a discount for being a 5K+ user, so it could be to confirm the discount and not just e.g. a friend emailing me the code. (But I know of some sites that deliberately let you get away with that sort of thing - it's new business after all.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few reasons.  Like you pointed out - its helpful to confirm the "high rep" discount.  Plus, we'd like to do a really awesome badge design including the SO profile.